# SQL group by LIKE pattern

Tags: sql, group-by

I have the following table:
what i want to do is group:
 group by `firstname` and `address` on this sort of data

```
| firstname | address
+-----------+----------
| alex      | 338 s. michigan 
| mark      | finger
| alex      | 338 south michigan
| ted       | port
```

But the group by will not return *similar* values of the `address` field.

Is there a pattern I can apply to the group by? I want to use the LIKE pattern system .  for example :

```
select firstname, address from t group by firstname, '%'+SUBSTRING(address,0,5)+'%'
```

but that query doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if the substring can appear in any position in another address, you can do a join like:

```
select a.id, a.addr, b.id as b_id, b.addr as b_addr from t a, t b where
    b.addr like concat('%', substr(a.addr, 0, 5), '%') and
    b.id <> a.id;
```

will return all records whose first 5 address chars appear anywhere inside another address.

or you can just ignore the stuff after char 5 with a group:

```
select firstname, substr(addr, 0, 5) from t group by firstname,
  substr(addr, 0, 5);
```

you might want to use a tool to normalize postal addresses, such as:

```
https://webgis.usc.edu/Services/AddressNormalization/Default.aspx
```

(free up to 2500 records)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to group by the first 5 characters of the address too, you can do this:

```
select firstname, MAX(address) AS Address
from t 
group by firstname, SUBSTRING(address,0,5)
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: not really, i'd like to use the LIKE pattern so I can filter at a broader range.